# Is Keyword Filtering/Dropdown possible for DT table?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am practicing shiny and DT package. I am wondering is Keyword Filtering/Dropdown possible for DT table? Right now, I have a table that looks like this

| Student | Fruit Like |
| --- | --- |
| Amy | Apple, Banana |
| Jacky | Orange |
| Peter | Apple |

When I used `filter = 'top'`, I get a dropdown with selections of "Apple, Banana", "Orange", "Apple". Is it possible to set the dropdown so I only have one type of fruit as a selection item? So that, for example, I get a dropdown list only Apple, Banana, and Orange, and when I select Apple, I will see both Amy and Peter like Apple.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in this case you should use `tidyr::separate_rows()` on your data frame and then `call DT::datatable()`

```
library(tidyr)
library(DT)
test_df <- tibble(student = c("Amy", "Jacky", "Peter"),
                  fruit_like = as.factor(c("Apple, Banana", "Orange", "Apple")))

test_df %>%
  separate_rows(fruit_like, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(fruit_like = as.factor(fruit_like)) %>%
  datatable(filter = "top")
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. As can be seen in the duplicate, all you need is `options = list(search = list(regex = TRUE))`.

Comment: Ah indeed, was redirected to this post from another location, the user wished to not use regex (suggested it separately) and have DT's dropdown menu function as a factor rather than use string input. When doing so without separating_rows we get the option Apple, Banana - rather than Apple. 

In a Shiny app it wouldn't be the way to go, but if restricted to DT's dropdown and a factor input even `options = list(search = list(regex = TRUE))`  doesn't seem to do the trick, as in selecting 'Apple' filters out Amy.

Comment: Sorry, that's to say we get the options:  Apple, Apple, Banana, Orange  - rather than Apple, Banana, Orange